# Nested loop to delete linked list members that are equal to another member is breaking. Isolated the issue to one line

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've been working on my linked list lab with the help of a tutor, but lost contact with them unfortunately a while ago and haven't been able to figure this out on my own.

My first while loop steps through the linked list one node at a time, and then proceeds to the second while loop which steps through the second one and compares it to the first.
This seems to be working fine. The problem however, is that when it deletes a member, it actually goes ahead and deletes two. It deletes the one before it, and the node it's supposed to.

I've isolated the problem to line 80 of list.cpp (below). I think that cursorOne's link_field pointing to cursor 2's link field is deleting all of the nodes in between the two cursors, and this isn't what I want.

So I guess I should have cursor 1's link field point to cursor 1 next's link field? I feel so close.. and the hard part of this lab is already done but I have yet to have the one last Eureka moment req'd but I've been looking at it a lot.

Here is the program: It should be pretty self explanatory. It uses the node class and then mutates it with the list class.

Well on second thought, I guess I can't link to code on ideone.com.
So I will try and make this as brief as possible and just post the loop.
Here is the [node](http://ideone.com/UnL0jv) and [list.cpp](http://ideone.com/Ln0Oma)

```
      while(currentItem != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Enter Second Loop" << endl;
        cout << currentItem->data_field << " Curse 2" << endl;

        //compare it
        if (nodeToFindDuplicatesOf->data_field == currentItem->data_field)
        {

         //prev->next = current->next to delete
            // in order to delete only one, I must find a way to set the link_field of the previous node to cursor 1 to
            // the link field of the node that's to be deleted
            cout << nodeToFindDuplicatesOf->data_field << "being removed" << endl;
            predecessor = currentItem->link_field;
            delete currentItem;

            currentItem = nodeToFindDuplicatesOf; //set cursor2 to cursor1

        }
        currentItem = currentItem->link_field;
    }
    nodeToFindDuplicatesOf = nodeToFindDuplicatesOf->link_field;
    if (nodeToFindDuplicatesOf)
        currentItem = nodeToFindDuplicatesOf->link_field;
}
```

}

Do I need a previous node pointer in my node class?

Comment: To begin with, you dereference `head` without checking if it's `NULL` or not.

Comment: To continue, what will happen when `cursorOne` is the same as `cursorTwo`? _And_ you set `cursorTwo` to `NULL` _before_ you try to delete it, meaning you have a memory leak as nothing will be deleted.

Comment: To end, I recommend you use a debugger to step through the code line by line, to see what really happen.

Comment: Also, I think you want to void list::removeDu{p}licateEntries() :)

Comment: Are you trying to **remove any consecutive duplicates** from the list? What exactly are you trying to achive. I didn't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Your analysis in locating the error is correct. To delete an item from a list you need a pointer to both the `currentItem` you want to delete (a.k.a `cursorTwo`), as well as its predecessor. Your `cursorOne` pointer however is *not* the predecessor of `cursorTwo`, but instead the pointer to some node you want to find the duplicates of.

To fix the error, *first of all* use meaningful names for your variables. `cursorOne` and `cursorTwo` are not meaningful at all and their names are most likely the origin of your error. Why not call them `nodeToFindDuplicatesOf` and `currentItem`? (or maybe you can come up with something even better.)

Then you need to introduce a new pointer to keep track of the predecessor of `currentItem`.

When `currentItem` needs to be removed set the `link_field` of its predecessor, then `delete currentItem` (without setting it to `NULL` beforehand).

Comment: Okay, thank you for the answer. I will first go and change my variable names. Should I declare this pointer as part of the node class itself or can I do it inside the actual loop?

Comment: @user2271589 I would declare the `predecessor` pointer within the first while loop. Unless you would like to implement a doubly linked list, but that's quite a bit more work and out of scope for this question.

Comment: Little bit confused still, so the only time I actually need to anything with the predecessor pointer is when current item needs to be removed?

Comment: @user2271589 You also need to update it on each iteration so it always points to the current node's predecessor.

Comment: okay, I just updated the code in the OP, I'm getting a  memory issue now so probably messed it up more than it was. Fragile! I'm not sure how to actually set it to the previous node of the currentItem, isn't that the same as the "nodeToFindDupesOf" pointer?